# Appropriately nest resources in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

My application has deeply nested resources, but after reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting, I've realized it's not wise to have these deeply nested resources. Here is the situation my routes are currently in.

```
resources :assortments do
  resources :comments do
    member do
      post :like
      post :unlike
    end
  end
  member do
    post :like
    post :unlike
  end
  resources :designs do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        post :like
        post :unlike
      end
    end
    member do
      post :like
      post :unlike
      get :likes
    end
  end
end
```

I want to know the proper way to organize this structure to make it less confusing and "proper". Or is what I have ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just specify the `shallow: true` on your top `resources :assortments` and should build shallow routes for all the nested routes automatically.

I also would move the `:comments` resource into a concern, kind of like that

```
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments do
    member do
      :like
      :unlike
    end
  end
end

resources :assortments, shallow: true do
  concerns :commentable
  ...
  resources :designs do
    concerns :commentable
  end
end
```

And on an unrelated topic, i'd consider making the `LikesController` to have a centralized likes handling resource, might save one some headache when you have polymoriphic liking thing going on.